# Using exchange with Google Apps Sync (GASMO)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, exchange, google-workspace

After recently going Google, my company realised that we needed to maintain ties to our existing corporate entity who are using exchange.

Has anyone successfully used GASMO and imported an exchange account into the same profile?

I've managed to bring them both into a single profile but have issues such as 0x800411F4 and no address book being located for the exchange account.

It would be easy to have 2 profiles I know but not at all convenient so looking to bring both into a single, shared profile.

Any help much appreciated.

S

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to have GASMO and Exchange work on the same profile the only option is to either have two profiles of configure one account as IMAP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you add some background informations?